# Regular Expression for URL

Tags: regex, url

The regular expression posted below is used to pick up URLs, including ones in the format such as `example.com`. However, I want it only to pick up on URLs that have a `www.` or `http`, `https`, etc. in the front. In other words, it should pick up `www.example.com`. It should not pick up `example.com`.

```
((((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?((www.|[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)([a-zA-Z]{2,8}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*)
```

Comment: So does it work or what?

Comment: Are you sure you want to only match US domains? Other countries have an extra dot in the TLD part: `www.bbc.co.uk` or `www.tmnet.com.my`.

Comment: This expression already works in regards to picking up URLs including subdomains. It's doesn't work in the sense that I want it to pick up only URLs that start with www. or http:

Philipp G has fixed this issue so the expression he updated is the best one for me.

Comment: That's a good point about the extra dot in the TLD part. I did not consider this initially. I'll need to look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement, with more examples (especially regarding your "picking up subdomain" comment)?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm try

`(((((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)|(www\.))((|[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)([a-zA-Z]{2,8}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.\,\;\?\'\+&%\$#\=~_-]+))*)`

EDIT:
Yeah, I didn't really test that one. Ok, I didn't test this one either but I looked at it REALLY carefully ;)

`(((((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)|(www\.))(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)([a-zA-Z]{2,8}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.\,\;\?\'\+&%\$#\=~_-]+))*)`

You should look into a good regex tester. I usually use Expresso but there are many others out there.

Comment: This one seems to cut off randomly. For example, when trying http://www.yahoo.com, it cuts off the .com. It also happens for other instances where http:// is used so it's not always at the .com.

Comment: @Mike: New expression, try it out.

Comment: Thanks! It's working a lot better. I'll do more thorough testing, but all previous issues seem to have been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Validate that the URI is well-formed with a regexp--use the one out of RFC 3986.    Validate that it is plausible with code.  Trying to combine the check for well-formed and plausible into one regexp is too difficult to get right.  See: [Need a regex to validating a Url...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068405/need-a-regex-to-validating-a-url-and-support-20-and/2083506#2083506)

Comment: Good point, probably easier to reject special cases after verifying the input is well formed.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your expression:

```
((((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?((www\.)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)([a-zA-Z]{2,8}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.\,\;\?\'\+&%\$#\=~_-]+))*)
```

A pretty good website to check your expressions here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Sorry. I replied too quickly without thoroughly testing. It does check for the www. etc. However, it no longer picks up URLs with a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.])(?:[^\s()<>]+|\([^\s()<>]+\))+(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)|[^`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’\s]))
```

It's the revised Liberal URL Regex from Daring Fireball.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This expression includes has an issue where it picks up everything that's before a www. or http:

For example:

asfjkljswww.yahoo.com

The regular expression would pick up everything on this line including the asfj-etc. This one I will post below seemed to be the most promising thus far:

(((((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)|(www\.))(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)([a-zA-Z]{2,8}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.\,\;\?\'\+&%\$#\=~_-]+))*)

Credit goes to FrustratedWithFormsDesigner for this expression.

Comment: @Mike: The regex I provided doesn't match `asfjkljswww.yahoo.com`, check again.

Comment: You're correct. I must've made a mistake when I copied it over. This works very well. Thank you for your help!