# Auto-link regular expression

Tags: php, regex, url

I am using a PHP function to automatically turn URLs in a text string into an actual link that people can click on. It seems to work in most cases, however I have found some cases where it does not.

I don't really understand regular expressions at all, so I was hoping someone could help me out with this.

Here is the pattern I'm currently using:

```
$pattern = "/(((http[s]?:\/\/)|(www\.))(([a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)?[a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\.[a-z]{2,2})?)\/?[a-z0-9.,_\/~#&=;%+?-]+[a-z0-9\/#=?]{1,1})/is";
```

However here are some links I have found that this pattern is not matching:

- www.oakvilletransit.ca - Not sure, but assuming it doesn't match because of the two-letter country code
- www.grt.ca - Another one with the .ca domain that is not working
- Several other .ca addresses
- freepublictransports.com - Addresses without www. or http:// in front of them. I would like these to work as well.
- www.222tips.com - Assuming it doesn't match because of the numbers at the beginning of the address.

Does anyone know how I can modify that regex pattern to match these cases as well?

**EDIT** - It should also match URLs that may have a period at the end. If a URL is the last part of a sentence there may be a period at the end that should not be included in the actual link. Currently this pattern takes that into account as well.

**EDIT 2** - I am using the pattern like this:

```
$pattern = "/((http|https):\/\/)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)?[a-z][a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z]{2,6}){1,3}(\/[a-z0-9.,_\/~#&=;%+?-]*)?/is";
  $string = preg_replace($pattern, " <a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>", $string);
  // fix URLs without protocols
  $string = preg_replace("/href='www/", "href='http://www", $string);
  return $string;
```

Comment: Regex tip: `[s]?` isn't necessary. Just use `s?`.

Comment: Regex tip: `{1,1}` doesn't make any sense. Neither does `{2,2}`.

Comment: Ok, I found this code on another SO question. So changing the [s]? to s? and removing the {1,1} and {2,2} shouldn't make a difference?

Comment: No, no difference. But make sure you replace the `{2,2}` with `{2}`; don't just take it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression for URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102727/regular-expression-for-url)

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate. The post you mentioned specifically says "It should not pick up example.com" whereas my question stated that I did want it to match that type of URL. So while the questions may have been similar, they are not duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following regex will match URLs:

- (Optionally) With `http://` or `https://`
- (Optionally) With a subdomain (`www.example.com`, `help.example.com`, etc)
- With 1-3 domain extensions, which each must be 2-6 characters (`www.example.com.gu`, `www.example.com.au.museum`, etc)
- (Optionally) With a forward slash at the end
- (Optionally) With valid characters after the forward slash

The `/i` at the end makes it case **insensitive**.

`/((http|https):\/\/)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)?[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z]{2,6}){1,3}(\/[a-z0-9.,_\/~#&=;%+?-]*)?/is`

**Edit:** This will not match any "hanging" periods at the end (such as the end of a sentence) because it's not part of the URL, and shouldn't be included in the `href` attribute of your link.

**Edit 2:** In your first `preg_replace()`, change `$1` to `$0`. This will insert the entire matched string instead of a single part of it.

**Edit 3:** (*Update 2*) Here's a better way you can check for a `http://` or `https://` at the beginning:

```
preg_replace("/href='[^h][^t][^t][^p][^s]?[^:]/", "/href='http:\/\/", $string);
```

Comment: ((http|https)://) should be ((http|https):\/\/) I've started using a # instead of a '/' as a delimiter when dealing with URL's, so you don't have to escape the forward slashes. And the    /i makes it case INsensitive.

Comment: Derp. Made this on regexbuddy, forgot to escape those two. Updated the answer, thanks. __Edit:__ I never knew you could use different characters for delimiters! This is great to know, thanks.

Comment: For some reason when I switch out the pattern I have for this one the links don't show up at all, even the plain text URL disappears in the text.

Comment: I am using the pattern like this:   $string = preg_replace($pattern, " <a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>", $string); There is also code to ensure that the http:// part is added if the text does not contain it already.

Comment: I have updated my question with the complete code I am using.

Comment: If you put `$string = "http://www.example.com/"`, and run it through the __first__ `preg_replace()`, what does `var_dump()` tell you it is?

Comment: Updated answer. Change `$1` to `$0`. Tested the `preg_replace()` on my own, this should work now.

Comment: Ok, getting closer. It is working on almost all of the links, except for two cases that I have found so far. The address www.222tips.com is changed to www.222 <a target='_blank' href='/out.php?url=tips.com'>tips.com</a> and the address freepublictransports.com doesn't get the http:// added to the beginning. I think I can get the second problem sorted out, but have no idea what to do for the first.

Comment: I derp'd and didn't let numbers be the first part of the URL after the subdomain (as you suggested in your question). I updated the pattern to allow them. `www.222test.com` matches correctly now. Also provided __edit 3__, which should help with your http:// problem.

Comment: Never mind, fixed that by adding a / at the end of the pattern in Edit 3

Comment: Actually still having a few problems. Adding the trailing / to the pattern got rid of the warning, but It's still not working properly. I am using it like this:

`if (!preg_match('/^http:\/\/|https:\/\//', $string)) {
str_replace("href='", "href='http://", $string);
}`

Comment: My bad, I forgot $string wasn't _just_ the URL. The updated __edit 3__ should work. Sorry for so many revisions! :P

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with all the examples above.

Here is one that works:

```
function autolink($string){
        $string= preg_replace("#http://([\S]+?)#Uis", '<a href="http://\\1">\\1</a>', $string);
        return $string;
}
```