# validating a url using Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate email address in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)
>   [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

I want to test that whether the string is url or not, right now I am stuck at this point.
I am using this regex to validate my URL
`/(https|http):\/\/([_a-z\d\-]+(\.[_a-z\d\-]+)+)(([_a-z\d\-\\\.\/]+[_a-z\d\-\\\/])+)*/;`

The problem with this regex is that it fails to validate this type of URL

`http://www.abc/abc/`

how to check that case.?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667070/javascript-regular-expression-to-validate-url and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303872/trying-to-validate-url-using-javascript

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303872/trying-to-validate-url-using-javascript), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url?lq=1), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102727/regular-expression-for-url?rq=1)...

Comment: Just for the sake of simplicity, `\w` catches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: I gone through the above links.. but my problem is that the regex i ma using is fine but if i remove .com or .in anything it also consider it a valid URL..

Comment: Shouldn't it validate `http://site.com/abc/`, for example?

Comment: @inhan It validates `http://site.com/abc/` but if i do like this `http://www.site/abc/` it validates this.. how to invalidate that case

Comment: It's extremely hard to make the regex determine if it is valid unless you list the acceptable whole range of extensions in your regexp. There are so many unusual possibilities out there. You might want to stick with some tried solution out there.

Comment: @Ajeet Pratap Maurya : please check my new answer and validate it if you think it suits your needs.