# Regex for Url Check

Tags: c#, regex, url-validation

In my "ServiceEditModel" class i have a property Url with typeof Uri. For validation I search a Regex that check if the Url, which is filled up on my "Edit" page, is valid. 
The Regex should check

1. Is there a http:// or https://
2. That the body only contains alphabetic characters and numbers
3. And the ending is like for example .com, .net, .ch
4. It should be possible, that there is another parameter behind the ending like for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions

My Code where the Regex comes in look like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ApplicationTemplate), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UrlRequired")]
[RegularExpression("REGEX COMES HERE", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ApplicationTemplate), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidUrl")]
public Uri Url { get; set; }
```

I already looked for Regex but can't find the right one because this is actually my first experiance with Regex.

Thanks for Help!

**EDIT**

I updated my regex so that it also allows url's with a "-" character such as http://www.comsoft-direct.ch/

Updated regex: `^(http|https):\/\/([\w\d + (\-)+?]+\.)+[\w]+(\/.*)?$`

Comment: and what hourly rates are you paying?

Comment: There's been talk of gTLDs coming to the domain name system for years. And yet you think it's reasonable, today, to implement something that limits the TLD?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a regex to validating a Url and support %20 and ()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068405/need-a-regex-to-validating-a-url-and-support-20-and)

Comment: Don't ever ever hardcode any rules like that in validation. The possible top level domains change all the time, the URL can use unicode (on some TLDs), there's a lot of things you have to check for (for example, `:` is valid in the URL, and once you add query string etc., almost any character is valid). If I were you, I'd just check that it starts with http(s)://, period. Everything else just begs for false negatives.

Comment: And of course, you can only use `:` once in the "hostname" part (for the port). Unless, of course, you're using IPv6. Really, don't bother. Someone will figure a way around the validation anyway, and you're just going to generate a lot of false negatives. It just isn't worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Regex should check simple scenarios according to **your constraints**. You can easily play with it and improve it *(which I strongly recommend, firstly because it's very simple at this state and secondly because you are a Regex beginner :))*.

```
^(http|https):\/\/[\w\d]+\.[\w]+(\/[\w\d]+)$
```

Check it on [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/dQ5sU4)

**Basic explanation:**

```
(http|https):\/\/
```

Should start with `http` or `https`, followed by `://`

```
[\w\d]+
```

Followed by N letters and/or digits

```
\.[\w]+
```

Followed by a `dot` and a set of letters. e.g.: `.com`, `.net` and such (note that you must change to `\.[\d\w]+` to allow digits also)

```
(\/[\w\d]+)
```

Followed, **optionally**, by a `/` and a set of letters and/or digits (e.g.: `/questions`)

**NOTE**: If you want a full-generic url validator, you must then google for that.

Comment: Why do I get 9 errors just by adding your Regex? Error Message: Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: You have to escape the backslashes on C#. Change your string to the following: `@"^(http|https):\/\/[\w\d]+\.[\w]+(\/[\w\d]+)$"`

Comment: So now I have to add the / at the end that it work is that right?

Comment: At the end of the Url e.g.: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions without /question it doesn't work

Comment: Of course it works. Check it here: http://regex101.com/r/fB5rS9

Comment: On my site it doesn't work.. O.o I have now the following Regex: @"^(http|https):\/\/[\w\d]+\.[\w]+(\/[\w\d]+)?$"

Comment: Do you have uppercase characters on the URL being tested? The current regex only matches lowercase characters. If that's the case, you should either change it to include upper case characters (replace every `\w` with `a-zA-Z`) or to make it whole case-insensitive (which I recommend) on the Regex options.

Comment: I didn't use any upper case characters in my URL...
now i replaced the \w but it still doesn't work...

Comment: What is the real URL you're trying to validate?

Comment: http://google.com
That failed...
When I added /bla it worked

Comment: Try this one then: `^(http|https):\/\/([\w\d]+\.)+[\w]+(\/.*)?$`

Comment: This one works many thanks! @Everton Agner